# Correct use of IdentifiedReference and { wrappedReference: true }

Tags: mikro-orm

With [this](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/66#issuecomment-564528360) I don't end of understand it and I don't want pollute the original issue. need I use always `{ wrappedReference: true }` with `IdentifiedReference`?

Because, this fail:

```js
@Entity({ collection: "account" })
export class AccountEntity implements IdEntity<AccountEntity> {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => ArtistEntity, "account", { wrappedReference: true })
    public artist!: IdentifiedReference<ArtistEntity>;
}

@Entity({ collection: "artist" })
export class ArtistEntity implements IdEntity<ArtistEntity> {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => AccountEntity, { wrappedReference: true })
    public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;
}
```

with:

> src/entities/artistEntity.ts(15,38): error TS2345: Argument of type '{
>   wrappedReference: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '"id" | "name" | "password" | "email" | "image" | "artist" |
>   "collections" | "studios" | ((e: AccountEntity) => any) | undefined'. 
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'wrappedReference' does not exist in type '(e: AccountEntity) => any'.

So, this would the correct?

```js
@Entity({ collection: "account" })
export class AccountEntity implements IdEntity<AccountEntity> {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => ArtistEntity, "account", { wrappedReference: true })
    public artist!: IdentifiedReference<ArtistEntity>;
}

@Entity({ collection: "artist" })
export class ArtistEntity implements IdEntity<ArtistEntity> {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => AccountEntity)
    public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use second parameter of `@OneToOne` decorator for options object, but that is currently supported only for first or third parameter

```js
// works if you use the default `TsMorphMetadataProvider`
@OneToOne()
public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;

// use first param as options
@OneToOne({ entity: () => AccountEntity, wrappedReference: true })
public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;

// use third param as options
@OneToOne(() => AccountEntity, undefined, { wrappedReference: true })
public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;

// you can also do this if you like
@OneToOne(() => AccountEntity, 'artist', { owner: true, wrappedReference: true })
public account!: IdentifiedReference<AccountEntity>;
```

But this will change before the final v3 release, so if you will use the `TsMorphMetadataProvider` (default one), it will always work even without the explicit `wrappedReference: true`.

Here is an issue you can subscribe to regarding this upcoming change: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/265

(it is about nullability, but this be another side effect of this change)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. (I am using `ReflectMetadataProvider`)